# Eclipse plugin: mock command line arguments during tests

Tags: eclipse-plugin, integration-testing, command-line-arguments

My eclipse plugin allows different setups, depending on the program arguments.
In the bundleActivator, I access these arguments like this `Platform.getCommandLineArgs()`

For testing, I would like to try different settings for the command line arguments.
Is there any way to modify the command line arguments during runtime?

A workaround would be to extract all relevant code to a class separate from the bundleActivator and then test that. But if possible, I would like to not do this.

Comment: I don't see any way to change the arguments. The value comes from `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.CommandLineArgs` which does not provide a public method to set the arguments.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for the clarification. I will then implement an singleton accessor class for the program arguments and mock that during tests.